# How to reduce the precision of a date (seconds)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a csv file, df, that I read with the following command :

```
pd_index=pd.read_csv(".../...",index_col="index",parse_dates=["created_at"])
```

The output is :

```
              created_at        ...         user_screen_name
index                            ...                         
0     2019-02-27 05:36:29        ...          realDonaldTrump
1     2019-02-27 05:31:21        ...          realDonaldTrump
2     2019-02-26 18:08:14        ...          realDonaldTrump
3     2019-02-26 04:50:37        ...          realDonaldTrump
```

I would like to have the following result :

```
              created_at        ...         user_screen_name
index                            ...                         
0     2019-02-27 05:36:00        ...          realDonaldTrump
1     2019-02-27 05:31:00        ...          realDonaldTrump
2     2019-02-26 18:08:00        ...          realDonaldTrump
3     2019-02-26 04:50:00        ...          realDonaldTrump
```

I tried the following command :

```
df.created_at=df.created_at.replace(second=0)
```

Unfortunately I get this error :

```
TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'second'
```

Is there someone who knows how I get get the desired result with replacing the seconds by 00?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) with minutes:

```
df.created_at=df.created_at.dt.floor('T')
#alternative
#df.created_at=df.created_at.dt.floor('min')
print (df)
           created_at user_screen_name
0 2019-02-27 05:36:00  realDonaldTrump
1 2019-02-27 05:31:00  realDonaldTrump
2 2019-02-26 18:08:00  realDonaldTrump
3 2019-02-26 04:50:00  realDonaldTrump
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of "hardcoded" but it may work:

```
df.created_at=df.created_at[:-3]+":00"
```